# C++ SendInput possible in Windows Service?

Tags: c++, windows-services, sendinput

First off, I'd like to say that I've used StackOverflow for years, and this is the first time I haven't found an existing answer.  A testament to what a valuable resource this is.

Background:
I'm trying to catch MIDI input from a connected device and have it trigger keyboard events to whichever window has focus.  I was able to do this successfully using SendInput in a Windows Console application, but would prefer to run this as a service.  I was able to hide the console window and have it work, which is a passable solution, but I would prefer to get it working without seeing the console for a second before it hides.

The problem:
After doing some research on making a Windows Service, primarily using the following sources:

[MSDN Windows Service Tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppWindowsService-cacf4948)

[CodeProject Windows Service Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus)

I got the impression that there might be security restrictions that prevent SendInput from working in a Windows Service (and understandably so).  I decided to try a proof of concept first before getting too far to see if I could get it to work.  I ran the sample code from MSDN and was able to get it to install and work as described in the tutorial.  After doing so, I added the following code to their example in the class SampleService.cpp:

```
    while (!m_fStopping)
{
    // Perform main service function here...
    INPUT keyEvents;
    keyEvents.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    keyEvents.ki.wScan = 0;
    keyEvents.ki.time = 0;
    keyEvents.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    keyEvents.ki.wVk = 0x41;
    keyEvents.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &keyEvents, sizeof(INPUT));
    ::Sleep(5000);  // Simulate some lengthy operations.
}
```

I did not change any other code.  After I installed the service, I found it listed in Services, and before starting it, I went into Properties, to the Logon tab, and set Logon to Local System Account and checked Allow Service to Interact with Desktop.  When running the service I don't see the lower case a I expect in any window that accepts text.

Is it possible to use SendInput in a service?  If so, how?  If not, is there another way to have a service send key events to any active window?

I'm using Windows 8 64bit, IDE is VS2012 Professional.

Comment: you really should'nt send messages from a service, nor should you even interact with the desktop and standard applications at all - thats bad application design and security restrictions wont make it easy. Write a normal application and have it auto-started instead, that wont get you into any trouble and should work flawlessly

Comment: If the application that you're sending the input to was launched *by the service* then SendInput might work, but it certainly won't be able to send input to an interactive application.  But from the sounds of it you don't need a service at all, you just need to rebuild your original application without a console.  (That is, using the Windows subsystem rather than the Console subsystem.)

Comment: Ah, yep, I had a misconception of what a service is.  Thanks Harry.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to conduct any interaction with the user from Windows Services. Services run isolated for security reasons. They run in a separate session, [session 0](https://www.2brightsparks.com/resources/articles/understanding-windows-sessions.pdf). 
So what you are trying to do, won’t work and for a reason.